# Why ajax update panel keeps waiting whereas request is processed completely at server. Is it case that data not received to ajax panel?

Tags: c#, ajax, azure

I am creating an azure application, which has database on azure sql server. On one of my page I have file upload control and I use it to upload excel file which has some data in one table in a first sheet. Like 50 rows and 8 columns. Now after uploading file I click on process button and I process each row and do some validations on each row and saves valid rows in database. Then I put this saved data on the pdf file. All this processing requires 2 seconds for each row. I have sent an asynchronous request using update panel.

At server side the request finishes i.e. rows are processed and saved in database but at client side I can see only ajax loader image on the page that data is coming from server please wait. It waits till asynctimeout which is I had put 1000 seconds in scriptmanager. It again sends request after timeout.

I am not understanding why is it waiting till time out and not showing me any message that number of rows processed and error occurred in rows, for which I am waiting? Also why is it resending request after time out? I

Can any one help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is the server responding that it is complete?  You should see some communication come back to the client.  You can also do something like this to handle the timeout error and not resend the request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function (sender, args) {  
            if (args.get_error() && args.get_error().name === 'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException') {  
                            args.set_errorHandled(true);  
            }  
        });  
</script>
```